# Как устроен Netty?

Tags: java, асинхронность, netty

Немного почитал про асинхронные сокеты и про фреймворк Netty, но у меня возник вопрос о том как устроен механизм обработки многочисленных запросов к Netty. Изучив немного код Netty, я что-то понял, но боюсь что о многих аспектах работы Netty у меня может возникнуть неправильное представление. Я сейчас попытаюсь описать механизм обработки запросов и если в чем-то буду неправ, прошу поправить, так как хочу окончательно разобраться в его работе.

1) В Netty есть селекторы, которые путем итерации по пулу запросов(без какой-либо стратегии выбора) выбирают очередной запрос для обработки, запросы как я понял обрабатываются строго в том порядке в котором они были получены сервером

2)Если Потоков обработки больше одного и каждый задействует селектор, то может быть так что на один запрос будут претендовать несколько потоков обработки, в таком случае как они синхронизированы между собой?

3) Одно соединение обрабатывается только одним конкретным потоком обработки или это соединение может обрабатываться несколькими потоками, допустим клиент подключился к Netty серверу и посылает  запросы и все эти запросы обрабатываются только одним потоком по очереди или же разные запросы от одного клиента могут обрабатываться разными потоками обработки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Стратегия селекторов зависит от выбранного транспорта, но да "запросы обрабатываются строго в том порядке в котором они были получены сервером".
2. Потоков по умолчанию столько, сколько процессоров, но выполняются они неконкурентно. Каждый метод хэндлера или колбэк выполняется в некоторый момент времени только одним потоком. Поэтому синхронизация не нужна, если всё делать правильно.
3. Читать предыдущий пункт. Лучше не иметь разделяемого состояния между хэндлерами, но в остальном весь execution flow можно рассматривать как однопоточный.

---

*Плюс дополнительные потоки могут использоваться для блокирующихся хэндлеров, которым назначается отдельная `EventExecutorGroup` при подключении к конвейеру.*